IntelliJ IDEA Cucumber Java Run configuration - wrong feature run
Since I've upgraded IntelliJ IDEA to latest version, I am having issues that when i do the following:
Open specific feature for example: src/test/resources/Features/iCore/BO/MAN/MAN_BO_Bonusing.feature and start scenario with name: BO Bonusing - Redeem Casino temporary bonus
It is starting BO Bonusing - Redeem Casino temporary bonus but from feature with path src/test/resources/Features/iCore/BO/AL/AL_BO_Bonusing.feature
Java version: 17
IntelliJ version IntelliJ IDEA 2024.2.1 (Community Edition)
Build #IC-242.21829.142, built on August 28, 2024
Cucumber for Java plugin version: 242.20224.159
Gherkin plugin version: 242.20224.159
Basically it is starting the scenario with same name but ignoring the Feature path.
Logs:
##teamcity[testSuiteStarted timestamp = '2024-08-30T01:52:35.952+0000' locationHint = 'classpath:Features/iCore/BO/AL/AL_BO_Bonusing.feature:1' name = 'AL - Back Office Portal - Bonusing page']
##teamcity[testSuiteStarted timestamp = '2024-08-30T01:52:35.952+0000' locationHint = 'classpath:Features/iCore/BO/AL/AL_BO_Bonusing.feature:739' name = 'BO Bonusing - Create Casino permanent bonus']
Additional info, runtimeOptions for main cucumber class can not see Feature or Glue value. It is also not present in System properties.
Cucumber java configuration
I've tried passing the $FilePath$ in the Program arguments but it is passing the root of project not the specific feature file location.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
